# How to pickle Keras custom layer?

Tags: python, keras, pickle

I write a custom layer class extends by Layer class, then I want to pickle the history for further analysis, but when I reload the pickle object from file, python raise an error:

> Unknown Layer: Attention.

So, how can I fix it?

I have both tried `get_config`, `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`, but it failed. I just want to pickle the keras history, but not the model, so please don't tell me the save model methods with `custom_object` parameters.

Comment: Could you please add reproducible code showing why your approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 12):

This problem occurs because when dumping the history, it fails to dump the full model. So when loading it, it cannot find the custom class.

I've noticed that the `keras.callbacks.History` object has an attribute `model`, and the incomplete dump of it is the cause of this problem.

And you said:

> I just want to pickle the keras history, but not the model

So following is a workaround:

```
hist = model.fit(X, Y, ...)
hist.model = None
```

By just setting the `model` attribute to None, and you can dump and load your history object successfully!

Following is the MVCE:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, Layer
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import pickle

# MyLayer from https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(28,28,3), activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(MyLayer(10))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

model.summary()

X = np.random.randn(64, 28, 28, 3)
Y = np.random.randint(0, high=2, size=(64,1))

hist = model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=8)

hist.model = None

with open('hist.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(hist, f)

with open('hist.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    hist_reloaded = pickle.load(f)

print(hist.history)
print(hist_reloaded.history)
```

The output:

> {'acc': [0.484375], 'loss': [6.140302091836929]}
>
> {'acc': [0.484375], 'loss': [6.140302091836929]}

P.S. If one wants to save keras model with custom layer, [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4871#issuecomment-329392660) should be helpful.